# RabbitMQ Channels and Connections

Tags: sockets, tcp, rabbitmq, amqp

I've trying to understand the concept of channels and connections in `RabbitMQ`, I understand it in a high-level, a **connection** is a real connection implemented as `TCP socket` to the broker, **channels** are virtual connections that use the sane real connection to communicate. So channels are multiplexed through the same connection.

However in a low-level how is this implemented, `TCP sockets` are non-blocking? I've read that using multiple connections don't increase performance why not ? When a channel uses the connection i imagine the calls are serialized right? So wouldn't multiple connections allow me to send and receive data faster.

I know I'm missing something here so that's why I'm asking for some clarification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a server or client uses non-blocking sockets is an implementation detail. An implementation that needs high performance probably uses non-blocking socket; but e.g. the RabbitMQ server uses the usual lightweight Erlang process model to achieve concurrency.

You are free to use multiple AMQP connections - though in most cases you should be good with one connection and multiple channels. TCP has a relatively high overhead, and multiplexing channels on top of a TCP connection reduces this overhead.